# Azure IoT Hub Authentication

Tags: authentication, azure-iot-hub

I understand that Azure IoT hub can use X.509 cert to authenticate an IoT device that wish to get connected to it. But when the IoT device is using X.509 cert, is there any mechanism for this IoT device to authenticate the IoT hub ?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the [Secure your IoT deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-fundamentals/iot-security-deployment?context=azure/iot-hub/rc/rc) article for IoT Hub on learn.microsoft.com - it summarizes recommended practices for ensuring the security of your IoT Hub solution.

Comment: Thanks Dominic for your advice. Now I know that the IoT Hub is authenticated by using a root cert.